# 403 error on post request that submits user input

Tags: node.js, ajax, passport.js, express-validator

I have a signup page with an email and password field. I also have a user-side `script.js` file that detects the value of the input fields and send them via 'post' request.

However when I enter both fields and click `sign up`, the terminal shows `POST /user/signup 403` and the browser just keeps loading until it time out. It seems like something is stopping the code from accessing the route but I don't know what.

I am using `express-validator 6.0.1` with `passport.js`.

Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

script.js:

```
$('#signup-btn').click(function () {
$.ajax({
  url: '/user/signup',
  type: 'POST',
  cache: false,
  data: {
    email: $('#email').val(),
    password: $('#password').val()
  },
  success: function () {
    $('#error-group').css('display', 'none');
    alert('Successfully signed up');
  },
  error: function (data) {
    $('#error-group').css('display', 'block');
    var errors = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
    var errorsContainer = $('#errors');
    errorsContainer.innerHTML = '';
    var errorsList = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
      errorsList += '<li>' + errors[i].msg + '</li>';
    }
    errorsContainer.html(errorsList);
  }
});
});
```

routes:

```
router.post("/user/signup",
[
  check('email', 'Your email is not valid').not().isEmpty().isEmail().normalizeEmail(),
  check('password', 'Your password must be at least 5 characters').not().isEmpty().isLength({min: 5})
],
function (req, res) {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  console.log(req.body);

  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).jsonp(errors.array());
  } else {
    passport.authenticate("local.signup", {
      successRedirect: "/user/profile",
      failureRedirect: "/user/signup",
      failureFlash: true
    });
  }
});

router.get("/user/profile", (req, res, next) => {
  res.render("user/profile");
});
```

Comment: see if there exists the CORS on your server, generally 403 means forbidden request i.e itself tells you that you can not access content of route to know more about cors please visit this site : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: You need to pass `req` and `res` to passport so it can respond `passport.authenticate("local.signup", {...})(req, res)`

Comment: @Molda Wow, thanks! `(req, res)` solved the problem :)